# Graph API - Not able to call (view) all messages in a thread

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

I'm trying to view all messages in a thread (i.e. I want to pull all messages in a conversation with a friend), however the api starts to return empty data lists [] when I move to the next "page" of results even though I am certain I have more messages (I can view those messages when I'm logged on to facebook). It's as if I have no more messages to view even though I definitely do. This is not an issue relating to LIMIT, although for one thread if I have LIMIT = 25, then it will show me the first 25 results and when I move to the next page of results it will not display anything. For that same thread, if I set limit to 500, then I'll be able to view the first 500 results and not see anything when I go to the next "page". However this behaivor seems arbitrary since so conversations I have with other friends Im often able to view a lot more (if not all of the conversation). Is facebook not showing us all of the messages through the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, but nothing you can do.

Currently how i handle this was: retrieve **LIMIT 20** messages perpage for a single thread. I found 50 messages perpage cannot get older messages too(for some threads).